# Are collection view cells reusable when they are inserted?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionreusableview

I'm working on a view controller, where collection view cells are inserted when user scrolls.

I use reloadData() method only at the beginning. (viewDidLoad)

After first load, I use insertItems(at:) method whenever user scrolls.

There are a lot of cells to be added, so cells should be reusable.

But I'm wonder if cells are reused when I insert cell directly.

Are cells reused when they are inserted? (not reloadData)

Comment: Yes, they are reused.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes, cells are reused.

Longer answer:

When you call `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)` to get a cell for an item in the collection view it would return a reusable cell object located by its identifier.

> Call this method from your data source object when asked to provide a
>   new cell for the collection view. This method dequeues an existing
>   cell if one is available or creates a new one based on the class or
>   nib file you previously registered.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618063-dequeuereusablecell)